# Convert Comma separated string to comma separated integer value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, integer, type-conversion

I have a one array like this.

```
Array ( [0] => 155 [1] => 156 [2] => 157 [3] => 158 [4] => 159 [5] => 160 [6] => 161 [7] => 162 [8] => 186 [9] => 163 [10] => 164 )
```

Now, I have to convert array to comma separated integer value.

But When, I use `implode(',',$arr)` then it count as a string.

But I need as an integer format value not a string format.

Comment: `(int)implode(',',$arr)` type cast your data

Comment: if you are going to compare them later on, you can use string to compare with int as php is not as strict as other language..http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: this function return first single value of the array I want all the value string to integer using implode function or any other function.

Comment: Store the imploded data in a variable then type cast that variable

Comment: it returns only a single value. not all the values I am using below codes. $crmIdss = implode(',',array_map( 'intval', array_filter( explode(',', $arr), 'is_numeric' ) ));
     $abc = (int)$crmIdss;
     
     
     var_dump($abc);

Comment: There is nothing called _"comma separated integer value"_ in PHP!! What do you want to do with that BIG integer?!

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr_data=array(155,156 ,157, 158, 159,160,161,162 ,186,163, 164 );
$str_data=implode(',',$arr_data);
$int_data_rc= str_replace(',','',$str_data);

print_r($int_data_rc); exit; 

// output will show
  155156157158159160161162186163164
```

Comment: Hey I need value like 155,156 and so on but as a integer value.